# Installation error of yum in mac 10.9.3

Tags: ios

I used `sudo port install yum` for install the yum in my mac(version 10.9.3). But when i executed the yum, for example `yum update`, it gives me the errors, like:

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

 No module named _rpm

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.5.6 (r256:Unversioned directory, Nov 18 2013, 16:32:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)]
```

I already double-checked that I have the `rpm` in my mac, so somebody knows which module i should install?

Comment: Why are you using Linux package managers - why not just macports and then plain OSX?

Comment: @Mark I want to install one library named sphere. I just follow the link http://pkgs.org/centos-6/repoforge-i386/sphere-2.6-1.a.2.el6.rf.i686.rpm.html

Comment: Those are Linux files for Cent OS so will not work on OSX you need to find an OSX version pks.org is for Centos